# Bulk import email aliases to Office 365 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, office365

I have a CSV file with list of users and aliases I would like to import to Office 365.

CSV is fortmated like this:

Recipient,AliasEmail
someone@mydomain.com,newalias@mydomain.com;someone@newdomain.com;newalias@newdoamin.com

I'm using this powershell command:

```
Import-Csv E:\aliases.csv | ForEach-Object{
>> $Recipinet = $_.Recipient
>> $ProxyAddresses = $_.AliasEmail -split ";"
>> Set-Mailbox -Identity $Recipinet -EmailAddresses @{add = $ProxyAddresses}
```

As a result I am getting:

**WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'someone' have been modified.**

Why is not adding the aliases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the command again - I've received same output but this time all aliases appeared in Office 365.